# Getting 100% accuracy on SVM classifier, tried everything, still 100% accuracy, is my model behaving correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, data-modeling

I have a small sample size (~150) and 35 features. I intend to classify based on the response variable (nearly 50:50 TRUE:FALSE) and I chose SVM classifier as my model.
Checked for duplicates in my X vector and found no duplicate values.
Then I went for the usual train-test split first. Due to my small sample size, I chose the test split ratio to be 0.4:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)
```

Then I scaled the data:

```
ST_Scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = ST_Scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = ST_Scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

Then I applied the SVM classifier with no hyperparameter optimization and got 100% accuracy on the training set.
Using cross-validation on the training set got me 95% accuracy:

```
scores = cross_val_score(SVC_model, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

Applying the model to the test data yielded me 98% accuracy.
After doing grid search on gamma and C and kernel, the model will yield me 100% accuracy on both test and training sets.

As an alternative I used nested cross-validation as described [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/) to the entire data, with the small change of adding scaling after the outer cross-validation is complete in each loop. I used k=10 for the outer cross-validation and k=5 for the inner cross-validation; and it gives an average of 100% accuracy on the test data.

I know that 100% accuracy is almost always questionable, however, I am running out of things to check. I triple checked the code and there are no obvious mistakes. changing the train-test split ratio doesn't change anything. Besides the fact that the small sample is probably inflating the accuracy of my model(and possible data sparsity), can I conclude that my model is acting reasonably? Is there anything else I can check for?

Comment: You shouldn't be scaling the training and testing sets separately, but I doubt that's the main issue.  The target isn't included also in `X`, is it?  Or maybe not exactly the target: is there anything very highly correlated with the target?

Comment: @BenReiniger Why shouldn't I scale them separately? I am new to this but as far as I have read, scaling them separately helps avoiding the mixture of train and test data. No there are no highly correlated variables in my X.

Comment: Sorry, "separately" was probably not the right word. You should use `fit_transform` on the training set, and just `transform` on the testing set. (When you cross-validate on the prescaled train, then you're also leaking from the test folds, but that's a separate issue.)  Maybe your problem really is just "easy"?